# How to implement a tri state button using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qpushbutton, tri-state-logic

I need to create a button which has three states:

- unclicked
- intermediate
- clicked

The logic I want to implement with this button is that whenever this button is clicked, I want the system to go to the intermediate state and wait for an event.

In other way when the state transition is `unclicked --> intermediate -- > clicked` and then `clicked --> intermediate -->unclicked`.

Does Qt support implementing this kind of button? If so, how?

Comment: what about using a normal button and giving it a different color (or change appearance somehow) for the intermediate state?

Comment: If you want to just iterate through all states then just create a button and inside create a state value of 0 then with each click just shift 1 to the left or to the right: `clicked -> state <<=1 | state >>=1` then you have 3 states with 0 being unclicked, 1 is indeterminate, 2 being clicked

Comment: Even a possible try is to reimplement QPushButton

Answer (score 6):

The nearest you have is `QCheckBox`. It already has a property for it: [`QCheckBox::setTristate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcheckbox.html#tristate-prop):

```
auto yourCheckBoxButton = new QCheckBox("Tristate button");
yourCheckBoxButton->setTristate(true);
```

You can do it on the Designer too (it is at the end of the properties list).

If you don't want to use a `QCheckBox`, a stylesheet and a custom property that is modified each time the button is pressed can do it:

```
auto pushButton = new QPushButton("Tristate button");
pushButton->setProperty("state", 0);
pushButton->setProperty("state-step", 1); // change to next state, 1 or -1
pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton[state=\"0\"] { background: red; }"
                          "QPushButton[state=\"1\"] { background: grey; }"
                          "QPushButton[state=\"2\"] { background: blue; }");
connect(pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [ = ](bool) {
  const int state = pushButton->property("state").toInt();
  const int step = state == 0 ? 1 :
                   state == 2 ? -1 : pushButton->property("state-step").toInt();
  pushButton->setProperty("state", state + step);
  pushButton->setProperty("state-step", step); // update in case it changed

  // Changing the property is not enough to choose a new style from the stylesheet,
  //  it is necessary to force a re-evaluation
  pushButton->style()->unpolish(pushButton);
  pushButton->style()->polish(pushButton);
});
```

Other more elaborated options would be to use a [`QProxyStyle`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html) or to re-implement the `QPushButton` class itself.

Comment: The tri-state is changing state like `A -> B -> C -> A`... if I remember well, isn't it ? Not `A -> B -> C -> B -> A` like it is asked.

Comment: @ymoreau thanks for pointing this out, I've updated the answer to cover it